# Only show filled attributes in leaflet popups (and not "null"-attributes)

Tags: null, popup, leaflet, geojson

My leaflet map shows polygons from a GeoJSON file. This file has several attributes (attribute_1, attribute_2, etc.). However, some are filled with text and some are empty.

**How can I only show the attributes which are filled with text in my popup and not the empty ones?**

Using my code beneath every attribute is shown and if it's empty "null" is shown in the popup:

```
// Integrate GeoJSON and style polygons
  $.getJSON("klimagutachten_2001.geojson",function(klimagutachten){
    L.geoJson( klimagutachten, {
        style: function(feature){
            return {
                color: "#e60000",
                weight: 4,
                fillColor: "#e60000",
                fillOpacity: .3
            };
        },

// Call popup
        onEachFeature: function( feature, layer ){
            layer.bindPopup("<strong> Attribute 1: \"" + feature.properties.attribute_1 + " and the second attribute is: " + feature.properties.attribute_2)
        }                                                                                                       
    }).addTo(map);
  });
```

Comment: There is a similar question already posted (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055382/remove-null-attributes-in-leaflet-popups-with-an-if-statement) but it doesn't answer mine.

Comment: Do you mean that you tried it and it did not work ?

Comment: It should work but I don't want the attributes not to be shown as asked. I want every attribute that isn't empty in the popup. So it's slightly a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question using a simple if...else statement. The additions are highlighted in bold:

```
// Integrate GeoJSON and style polygons
  $.getJSON("klimagutachten_2001.geojson",function(klimagutachten){
    L.geoJson( klimagutachten, {
        style: function(feature){
            return {
                color: "#e60000",
                weight: 4,
                fillColor: "#e60000",
                fillOpacity: .3
            };
        },

// Call popup
        onEachFeature: function( feature, layer ){
        var attribute_1 = feature.properties.attribute_1;
        if (attribute_1 == null) {
            attribute_1 = "";
        } else {
            var attribute_1 = feature.properties.attribute_1;
        };

            layer.bindPopup("<strong> Attribute 1: \"" + attribute_1 + " and the second attribute is: " + feature.properties.attribute_2)
        }   
    }).addTo(map);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a validation:

```
onEachFeature: function( feature, layer ){

var text = "";

if (!feature.properties.attribute_1) {
    text += feature.properties.attribute_1 +" "; 
}
if (!feature.properties.attribute_2) {
    text += feature.properties.attribute_2 +" "; 
}
layer.bindPopup(text);

}
```

Comment: With my limited programming knowledge I'm unfortunately no capable to get the code running. Could you please assist where to paste it exactly. Thanks!

Comment: thx for editing but it doesn't work. Polygons with both attributes are now completely empty and polygons with only one of the two attributes show only "null"...