# Show not null attributes in Mapbox GL JS popups

Tags: javascript, popup, mapbox

My Mapbox map shows points with different attributes (~300 columns).
Most of attributes for each point are nulls.
How can I show only the attributes which aren't nulls (or >0) in popup?

Usually I set popup content using simple code inside `var popup`
 like:

```
.setHTML("attr_1: " + feature.properties.attr_1 + "attr_2: " + feature.properties.attr_2)
```

I found [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562830/only-show-filled-attributes-in-leaflet-popups-and-not-null-attributes) for Leaflet, but nothing for Mapbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over properties, filter them out based on your condition, and then build popup content as a string.

Consider an example:

```
const feature = {
  properties: {
    attr1: 'text',
    attr2: null,
    attr3: 42,
    attr4: null,
    ...
  }
};

const popupContent = Object
  .keys(feature.properties)
  .reduce((acc, property) => {
    const value = feature.properties[property];

    // your condition here
    if (value) {
      acc.push(`${property}: ${value}`);
    }

    return acc;
  }, [])
  .join(', ');

console.log(popupContent) // attr1: text, attr3: 42
```

Comment: Thanks, Stepan. Works perfectly.